# How can I move one section to the right without screwing it on the fullresponsive view?

Tags: html

I am having a problem with one section that is aligned too much to the left.

It's  a template which the section have four boxes with text horizontaly placed one on the side of the other one  but I need only three so I deleted the last one.
And now i have 3 boxes with the space of that fourth empty so the 3 boxes are not on the center

so in the full responsive view i have this boxes but they are vertically placed one on top of the other in the center of the screen .I want it centered and I don't know how to do it without moving also it on the full responsive view!

I tried padding some stuff or margin left but when it looks centered on the full view it looks too much to the right on the full responsive view.
This is the code for the seccion

this is the link with the style.css on it ! https://jsfiddle.net/nbyz2n9h/3/
this is the link of the pics https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByV5FtEdheT_flRqQ1hZczNYeXN6SE9uUnNfcVVtenhIUXJTYXB2bTJoM0JMS3ljV0t5MmM&usp=sharing

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="box-gray aligncenter">
                                <h4>Prensa</h4>
                                <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                 Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium sprea totam rem aperiam.
                                </p>

                            </div>
                            <div class="box-bottom">
                                <a href="#">Ver más</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the CSS to run this with.

Better yet, paste it here, save it, and update your post above so we see exactly what the problem is

https://jsfiddle.net/nbyz2n9h/2/

```
enter code here <section id="content">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="box-gray aligncenter">
                            <h4>Prensa</h4>
                            <div class="icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                             Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium sprea totam rem aperiam.
                            </p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="box-bottom">
                            <a href="#">Ver más</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

What I think you mean and want to do

|-------------|-------------|

| ..box 1...   | ...box 2/..       |

|-------------|-------------|

| ...........Box 3 ...........|

|---------------------------|

Is this right?

- After seeing the image I think this is the behavior you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/nbyz2n9h/14/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-gray">
                <h4>Prensa</h4>

                <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x">Box image ?</i>
            </div>
            <p>Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium sprea totam rem aperiam.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-bottom">
                <a href="#">Ver más</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-gray">
                <h4>Box 2</h4>

                <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x">Box image ?</i>
            </div>
            <p>Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium sprea totam rem aperiam.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-bottom">
                <a href="#">Ver más</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-gray">
                <h4>Box 3</h4>

                <div class="icon"> <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x">Box image ?</i>
            </div>
            <p>Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium sprea totam rem aperiam.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-bottom">
                <a href="#">Ver más</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br style="clear:both;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* --- box --- */
.container {
    text-align:center;
}
.row {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}
 .box {
    /* The boxes are liqid and will increase with browser size. 
    if you want them to stay at a certain width, apply a pixel value to .row */
    width: 30%;
    margin:1%;
    float:left;
}
.box-gray {
    background: #999999;
    padding: 20px 20px 30px;
}
.box-gray h4, .box-gray i {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box-bottom {
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#ff00ff;
}
.box-bottom a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.box-bottom a:hover {
    color: #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Ok i just update with the link ! so that html that i post is for one of the boxes, i have 3 more right ? .. and then for example  the original page is like this .... --O O O O-- .... and i need  --O O O--. But when o delete on , it gets      --O O O   --  ... i would like to place the 3 of them centered , bt maybe what you say is good also

PD:i put also a link with some pictures

Comment: From what I now understand, you just want to center the 3 boxes. Ok that's easy enough. The boxes need to be placed in 2 parent containers - one with "text-align:center;" one with "width:pxvalue; margin:auto;" And that will center them across any browser.

I updated the answer I gave with the example and a link to a JS fiddle.
If it doesn't look "right" 
add a max width to .row
max-width:800px;
This will make the boxes inside the row never be smaller then (800/100)* 30 pixel, but as wide as they can be within 80% of the page.

Comment: Awsome brother that helped,thank you !!!.But the is one thing.when i put the website on  my cellphone the boxes get really tight and thin , and the text of each one is slightly out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to center your elements on a page

```
{ margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

Comment: no , it doesnt help , i update the question , maybe now u can understand a little better , sorry for the english ! haha